# What does this symbol in relation to Taylor series signify?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

The Taylor Series of a function f at an input 0 is :

$\sum \limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac {f^k(0)} {k!} x^k = f(0) + \left.\frac {df}{dx}\right|_0 x+ \frac 1{2!} \left. \frac {{d^2}f} {d{x^2}}\right|_0x^2 + \dots$

$\left.\frac {df}{dx}\right|_0 x$ : f at 0 + the derivative at 0 times x

What does symbol $|_0$ signify?

At first I thought it signifies derivative at 0 but I've seen it used in functions where input is not 0 .

Update : 
My mistake : I misread the literature : this is invalid : 'At first I thought it signifies derivative at 0 but I've seen it used in functions where input is not 0 .'

Comment: Can you show the context where you have seen other uses? I only know the one you mention.

Comment: @AugSB please see update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means evaluate the expression preceding with the variable set to 0. In the case where multiple variables appear, the subscript denotes which variable is set.

Answer (score 1):

It means evaluate, for instance

$$\frac{\mathrm{d} f(x)}{\mathrm{d} x} \bigg |_{x=x_0}=f'(x_0),$$

i.d. compute the first derivative of $f(x)$ and evaluate it at $x=x_0$.

It is often used for evaluate the definite integrals,

$$\int_a^b f(x) \mathrm d x = F(x) \bigg |_a^b=F(b)-F(a),$$

where $F(x)$ is a primitive of $f(x)$.